# Has my collegue reproduced the exact behavior of Task.WhenAll<TResult>?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, wait

When reviewing work by a contractor, I came upon the following extension method:

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> WhenAllSynchronousExecution<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var results = new List<TResult>();
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            if (task == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tasks));
            }
            
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                exceptions.Add(new OperationCanceledException("Tasks collection cancelled", token));
                break;
            }

            try
            {
                results.Add(await task);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        
        if (exceptions.Any()) {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
        
        return results;
    }
}
```

To this looks to be exactly what [`Task.WhenAll<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0)))))) already does. quote the remarks:

> The call to WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>) method does not block the calling thread. However, a call to the returned Result property does block the calling thread.
>
> If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks.
>
> If none of the supplied tasks faulted but at least one of them was canceled, the returned task will end in the Canceled state.
>
> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the resulting task will end in the RanToCompletion state. The Task.Result property of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks in the same order as they were provided (e.g. if the input tasks array contained t1, t2, t3, the output task's Task.Result property will return an TResult[] where arr[0] == t1.Result, arr[1] == t2.Result, and arr[2] == t3.Result).
>
> If the tasks argument contains no tasks, the returned task will immediately transition to a RanToCompletion state before it's returned to the caller. The returned TResult[] will be an array of 0 elements.

So to me it seems they've recreated an existing method. The only difference seems to be the checking of the `CancellationToken`, but I don't see mych added value there (it's not used in the code). And maybe that it's an extension method, but that's also not used in the code (it's called like `var task = TaskExtensions.WhenAllSynchronousExecution(tasks);`)

But this colleague is quite "sensitive". So I need to pick my battles. So is this just a custom,meagre recreation of `Task.WhenAll<TResult>`?

Comment: This seems a lot more like an interpersonal problem rather than a technical one. Why not ask them what this does differently that `Task.WhenAll` doesn't do?

Comment: @MindSwipe It's even more complex. Last time I had a similar discussion, it took half a day. Then it was followed by a discussion with my boss because they charge $$$ per hour. Maybe I should ask this on Code Review Stack Exchange...

Comment: Has the "collegue" written test code for this method and can you replace it with Task.WhenAll in the tests still satisfying the test criteria?

Comment: @Ralf nope. this is just used in two places.

Comment: Update: I talked to the colleague. It turns out he added this because using normal WhenAll crashed the app every now and then. This custom version "fixed" it. So it was probably a workaround to some bad async code somewhere else. I removed it for now and will look at the crash when it occurs again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there are quite a lot of differences between the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) and the `WhenAllSynchronousExecution`. Here are some of them:

1. The `Task.WhenAll` materializes immediately the `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` sequence, by enumerating it and storing the tasks in an array. This ensures that all the tasks are up and running, before attaching continuations on them. The `WhenAllSynchronousExecution` doesn't do that, so it could potentially start each task after the completion of the previous task (sequentially), depending on how the enumerable sequence is implemented.
2. <del>The `Task.WhenAll` doesn't take a `CancellationToken`, so when it completes you can be 100% sure that **all** the tasks have completed. It is always possible to fire-and-forget a `Task.WhenAll` task, just like any other `Task`, with the [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) method (.NET 6), so there is no reason to bake this functionality in every async method.</del>
3. The `Task.WhenAll` propagates the exceptions directly, as the `InnerExceptions` of the [`Task.Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property. The `WhenAllSynchronousExecution` wraps the exceptions in an additional `AggregateException`. So you can't switch between the two APIs without rethinking your exception-handling code.
4. The `Task.WhenAll` completes as [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) when none of the tasks is `Faulted`, and at least one is `Canceled`. The `WhenAllSynchronousExecution` propagates the cancellation as error, always.
5. The `WhenAllSynchronousExecution` captures the `SynchronizationContext` in its internal `await` points, so it might cause a deadlock if the caller [blocks on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).
6. The `Task.WhenAll` checks for `null` task instances synchronously. The `WhenAllSynchronousExecution` does the check during the loop that awaits each task.

---

**Correction:** Actually the integrated `CancellationToken` is a useful feature, that has been [requested](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67392) on GitHub.

Comment: From the name of the method, it looks like they *expect* that (1) will *cause* sequential execution, rather than that being entirely under the control of whatever is producing that `IEnumerable<Task>` - i.e. typical "user new to async" confusion of thinking that `await` *starts* the work.

Comment: Thx! You can pass the cancellation token to each of the individual tasks though.

Comment: @​JHBonarius sure. Canceling the tasks is almost always better than cancelling just the awaiting of the tasks, and then letting the tasks continue running unattended.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to figuring out if this method has any reason to exist is to confirm if the tasks are started before the method is called.

1. If the tasks are not started then the method should probably be called `~WhenAllSequential`.
2. If the tasks are started then this method seems not to add anything good.

---

In any case, I would argue against having this method as an extension method:

1. Having this method shown in auto-completion hints will sooner or later make someone pass already started tasks and think the tasks will be executed sequentially but it's the caller of this method who is in charge when the tasks are started.
2. Even the official `WhenAll` is not an extension method.